# i want to toggle between two functions this code works only one time but i want to make it work each time i click

Tags: javascript

```
let callOne = true;
let hamburger = document.getElementById("hamburger");

hamburger.addEventListener("click", (e) => {toggleFct();});

function one() {t1.play();callOne = false;}

function two() {t0.play(); callOne = true;}

function toggleFct() { callOne ? one() : two();}
```

let t1 = gsap.timeline({ paused: true, reversed: true });

t1.to(".div-first", { ease: "power2.in", x: "-200%", duration: 2 });

t1.to(".div-second", { ease: "power2.in", x: "-300%", duration: 2 },"-=2");

t1.to(".div-third", { ease: "power2.in", x: "-400%", duration: 2 }, "-=2");

t1.to(header, { ease: "power2.in", x: "-400%", duration: 2 }, "-=2");

t1.to(wrap, { ease: "power2.in", x: "-400%", duration: 2 }, "-=2");

let t0 = gsap.timeline({ paused: true, reversed: true });

t0.to(".div-first", { ease: "power2.in", x: "100%", duration: 2 });

t0.to(".div-second", { ease: "power2.in", x: "200%", duration: 2 }, "-=2");

t0.to(".div-third", { ease: "power2.in", x: "300%", duration: 2 }, "-=2");

t0.to(header, { ease: "power2.in", x: "400%", duration: 2 }, "-=2");

t0.to(wrap, { ease: "power2.in", x: "0%", duration: 2 }, "-=2");

Comment: [Should work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/woe61m98/). Where do `t0` and `t1` come from?

Comment: i just edited the post , sorry i forgot to add all the code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When I try to do the following :

```
let callOne = true;

function one() {console.log("one");callOne = false;}

function two() {console.log("two"); callOne = true;}

function toggleFct() { callOne ? one() : two();}
```

It works just fine...

btw you can rewrite

```
hamburger.addEventListener("click", (e) => {toggleFct();});
```

as...

```
hamburger.addEventListener("click", toggleFct)
```

Comment: thank you you just helped me to realize the problem which is Gsap work only one time and need to be refreshed now i'm trying to find a solution for that you were a big help

Comment: i found the solution for that problem thank  you again

Answer (score 0):

let callOne = true;
let hamburger = document.getElementById("hamburger");

hamburger.addEventListener("click", (e) => {toggleFct();});

function one() {t1.play(0);callOne = false;}

function two() {t0.play(0); callOne = true;}

function toggleFct() { callOne ? one() : two();}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).